# Creating a linear model matrix in R without intercept

Tags: r, regression

Creating a design matrix for linear models gave me an output that I didn't understand. Say I want to add two grouping variables:

```
model.matrix(~ factor(c(0,0,0,0,1,1)) + factor(c(0,0,1,1,0,0)))
```

This creates a three column design where the first is the intercept. But when I supress the intercept:

```
model.matrix(~ 0 + factor(c(0,0,0,0,1,1)) + factor(c(0,0,1,1,0,0)))
```

now again three columns are created, only the first and second are 0 and 1 versions of the same variable.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

When you put a factor in `model.matrix` it includes dummies for all the levels it can; when you have a two-level factor, you have dummies (indicators) for both levels.

With no intercept, the first factor can include all its levels, so it does, but when there's an intercept, that would lead to perfect multicollinearity (the sum of all the indicators for a factor is constant), and by default the indicator for the first level of the factor is then omitted.

With the *second factor*, it can't include all its levels in either case, because there will be multicollinearity with either the intercept (when it's in the model) or the first factor (when it isn't).

Comment: Thank you, but I am missing one crucial piece of information - I understand multicollinearity and why it doesn't create the extra levels in the first case, but I am unclear with the "it creates all levels it must". The two models are numerically identical if I am seeing this correctly. If I suppress the intercept, shouldn't the design matrix have one column less to make a different model?

Comment: 1. I chose to say "can" rather than "must"; I think that tends to give a more correct impression of the situation. 2. Each of your two-level factors has *two* corresponding indicator variables, and model matrix will include both *if it possibly can*.. I suggest you'll be less confused if you start by giving your factor levels the labels "A" and "B"  (or indeed almost anything else) in place of "0" and "1".